# Possibilities to filter a dataset on multiple conditions at once in R

Tags: r, dataset, filtering, data-manipulation

I am a passionate R user since 5 months and I am doing my whole research stuff with `R` (from Import, Tidying, Stats, Figures). I have a dataset with a primary key (`ID`). Linked to each `ID` are two factor variables (`Factor 1` has three levels, `Factor 2` has two levels) and a continuous variable (called `Variable`).

The desired data.frame would be the following:
Blocks of 6 `ID` rows like this:

```
        ID    Factor 1 Factor 2 Variable

1   1003617009  Lev 1   Lev 1   1176.455
2   1003617009  Lev 1   Lev 2   1165.669
3   1003617009  Lev 2   Lev 1   1134.951
4   1003617009  Lev 2   Lev 2   1115.436
5   1003617009  Lev 3   Lev 1   1212.339
6   1003617009  Lev 3   Lev 2   1186.782
```

That said, for each `ID`, `Factor 1`, `Factor 2` and `Variable` there is a unique combination. The raw dataset is really messy (different number of `ID`s (ranging from 1 to 17), different number of levels of factors per `ID` block, missing values etc.

I have to admit: I already found a solution for my problem. But the code is really not nice and I think very redundant and ineffective. My solution is the following:

```
# Import

df_raw <- read_excel("df_raw.xlsx", sheet = 1)

# Selecting relevant columns and deleting nas

df_relevant <- df_raw %>%
  select(ID, Factor1, Factor2, Variable)%>%
  na.omit()

any(is.na(df_relevant))
```

Then, filtering in blocks and closing the circle while constantly inner joining.

```
df_6 <- df_relevant %>%
  group_by(ID)%>%
  count()%>%
  filter(n == 6)

df_2 <- df_6 %>%
  inner_join(df_relevant, key = "ID")%>%
  group_by(ID, Factor1)%>%
  count()%>%
  filter(n == 2)

df_3 <- df_2 %>%
  inner_join(df_relevant, key = "ID")%>%
  group_by(ID, Factor2)%>%
  count()%>%
  filter(n == 3)

df_final <- df_3 %>%
  inner_join(df_relevant, key = "ID")%>%
  group_by(ID, Factor1, Factor2, Variable)%>%
  count()%>%
  filter(n == 1)%>%
  select(-(n))
```

This leads to the desired output. However I am pretty sure that there is a more elegant solution for this specific problem.

I tried using `ddply` from the `plyr` package without success. Then I though a lot about a possible solution with `data.table`, but was not successful at all here.

I would be delighted about a discussion on possible solutions.

Thank you so much,
David

Comment: In the first step, are you doing a self-join

Comment: In the code, did you meant `by = "ID"`

Comment: youre right. this is of course a mistake in the code. I will edit the code accordingly

Comment: where exactly do you mean by  = "ID"? in the group_by function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the joining is done iteratively with the output of each subsequent joins, a `for` loop would be useful

```
# create a grouping list for each run
grpLst <- list("ID", c("ID", "Factor1"), c("ID", "Factor2"),
         c("ID", "Factor1", "Factor2", "Variable"))
# corresponding filter values
filtVal <- c(6, 2, 3, 1)    

# initialize tmp as the 'df_relevant'
tmp <- df_relevant

# loop through the sequence of 'grpLst'
for(i in seq_along(grpLst)) {
      # join the tmp with df_relevant
      # grouped by the grpLst elements
      # get the frequency count
      # filter the rows based on 'filtVal' elements
      # update the tmp by assignment
      tmp <- tmp %>%              
           inner_join(df_relevant, by = "ID") %>%
           group_by_at(vars(grpLst[[i]])) %>%
           count() %>%
           filter(n == filtVal[i])  



}

df_final <- tmp %>%
              select(-n)
```

Comment: Ok thank you so much! I think I understand your solution. This looks much better.